# Raw DB querying in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, pg

I'm trying to run the following raw query in rails, only to see it fail:

```
query   = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ($1);'
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query, "My query", [ [1,2] ]);
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

The error I'm getting starts with this:

```
Could not log "sql.active_record" event. NoMethodError: undefined method `binary?' for 1:Fixnum
```

Clearly, I'm misusing `[1, 2]` bind params somehow, but I couldn't find a proper example myself.

P.S. This is minimal failing example, derived of a much more advanced query that can't be turned into ActiveRecord chain of calls. In other words – I can't rely on Arel when building my query.

P.P.S. I'm using `rails 4.0.1` and `postgresql 9.3`

Comment: I am not sure about postgresql since I usually query for MySQL. But anyways, the syntax should be same. Try:

`query   = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (?);'`

`results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query, [1,2])`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your NoMethodError is coming from the logging stuff. If we look [`exec_query`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb#L136), we see this:

```
def exec_query(sql, name = 'SQL', binds = [])
  log(sql, name, binds) do
    # call exec_no_cache(sql, binds) or exec_cache(sql, binds)...
```

Then if we look at [`exec_cache`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L789), we see this:

```
def exec_cache(sql, binds)
  #..
  @connection.send_query_prepared(stmt_key, binds.map { |col, val|
    type_cast(val, col)
  })
```

so the `binds` are supposed to be column/value pairs. The PostgreSQL driver expects `col` to be a column object so that it can ask it what its name is and how it should format the `val`, that information is used by the `log` call in `exec_query` to produce something pretty and human-readable in the Rails logs. A bit of experimentation suggests that you can use `nil` as the `col` and everything is happy.

That means that we've moved on to this:

```
exec_query(
  'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ($1)',
  'my query',
  [ [nil, [1,2]] ]
)
```

The underlying driver may or may not know what to do with the `[1,2]` array, I only have Rails3 with the PostgreSQL extensions available to test and it doesn't like the `[1,2]`. If Rails4 also doesn't like the array then you can pass the arguments one-by-one:

```
exec_query(
  'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ($1, $2)',
  'my query',
  [ [nil,1], [nil,2] ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue lately. It turns out that in the `where in (?)`, ActiveRecord is expecting a string, not an array. So you can try passing in a string of comma-separated ids and that should do the trick.

Comment: I ran into this issue too but solved it by doing this:
`sql = "SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE identifier IN (?)"`
`where_equals = ["id_1", "id_2"]`
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, [sql, where_equals]))`

Comment: the `(?)` syntax did not work for me at first.  I switched to using the alternate `'%s'` syntax and then eventually hash syntax.  ```e.g.

sanitize_sql_array(["name=:name and group_id=:group_id", name: "foo'bar", group_id: 4])
# => "name='foo''bar' and group_id=4"

sanitize_sql_array(["name='%s' and group_id='%s'", "foo'bar", 4])
# => "name='foo''bar' and group_id='4'"
``` from https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_array